# Error in query (1064) Syntax error in replace query Limit

Tags: mysql

Following query throws syntax error

> Error in query (1064): Syntax error near ' 200' at line 1

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace( column , 'search', 'replace') ORDER BY file_id ASC LIMIT 0, 200
```

but this works fine.

```
 UPDATE table SET column = replace( column , 'search', 'replace') ORDER BY file_id ASC LIMIT 0
```

but when I set two limits it throws a syntax error.

Should not use the **replace** keyword with two limits?

**MySQL version: 5.5.5-10.1.30-MariaDB**

Comment: There is no `offset` in the `LIMIT` clause of the [`UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html); there is only `row_count`. [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) is not involved in any way into the error.

Comment: The limit clause in an update statement does not have an offset option.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html as opposed to a select statement (for example) which does.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: Thanks, guys, How stupid I am :p, Anyway `Between` keyword works fine for my need

Answer (score 0):

As @axiac and @P.Salmon mentioned in comment.

> The limit clause in an update statement does not have an offset option

And  I have to use [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) keyword.

```
 UPDATE table SET column = replace( column , 'search', 'replace') WHERE file_id BETWEEN 0 AND 200
```

Comment: it will not update files with id > 200 so if you create 210 files and delete 10...this query will update till 190 files because 190 files will have ids somewhere less or equal to 200

Comment: Thanks for input @DanyalSandeelo , Yes you are correct, I have to get the MAX(file_id) before iterating query in the loop.